# rake db:migrate will giving me the error

Tags: ruby

When I run
`rake db:migrate`
it shows these warnings. How do I get rid of this?

```
DEPRECATION WARNING: railtie_name is deprecated and has no effect. (called from <class:Engine> at /home/shajin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/bundler/gems/spree_paypal_express-073f2f814dd8/lib/spree_paypal_express.rb:5)
WARNING: 'require 'rake/rdoctask'' is deprecated.  Please use 'require 'rdoc/task' (in RDoc 2.4.2+)' instead.
    at /home/shajin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/rdoctask.rb
WARNING: Global access to Rake DSL methods is deprecated.  Please include
    ...  Rake::DSL into classes and modules which use the Rake DSL methods.
WARNING: DSL method Soletronspree::Application#task called at /home/shajin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/railties-3.0.7/lib/rails/application.rb:215:in `initialize_tasks'
WARNING: 'task :t, arg, :needs => [deps]' is deprecated.  Please use 'task :t, [args] => [deps]' instead.
    at /home/shajin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/deface-0.5.2a/tasks/deface.rake:3:in `block in <top (required)>'
rake aborted!
undefined method `to_sym' for ["Bit.ly", "bitly"]:Array

Tasks: TOP => db:migrate => environment
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Comment: Run it with `--trace- to get a full stack trace of where the problem occurred, and paste that.

Answer (score 0):

Is the app written in an older version of Ruby than the one your are trying to run it on? This could be the issue. Try to update the code to ruby1.9.2 and then check.